# Run a webserver on an iOS device

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, http

I want to create an App that can share files between other iOS devices and potentially also Desktop computers.

So what I want to do is run a lightweight web server on my device that allows to download files from the device like so:

http://myphone.local:1234/folder/samplefile.txt

How can I provide such a server on a non-jailbroken device. I would prefer not to write a server like this from scratch :-).

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Would a web service be ideal for what you want?

Comment: @Carl I need the iOS device to act as a web server. So the iOS device is not the client in my case.

Comment: ahhh ok i read the question wrong sorry bout that

Comment: What did you decide to use for the lightweight web server?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at [Cocoa HTTP Server](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out one out. I guess I've stumbled upon it some while back. It definitely looks promising

Comment: Sure I'll do this, bug I need to test it first.

Comment: Does Apple Approve this cocoaHTTPServer, if i make use it in my App? Couple of days back my App is rejected by Apple for making use of RoutingHTTPServer.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [GitHub project](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer):

> CocoaHTTPServer is a small, lightweight, embeddable HTTP server for
>   Mac OS X or iOS applications.
>
> Sometimes developers need an embedded HTTP server in their app.
>   Perhaps it's a server application with remote monitoring. Or perhaps
>   it's a desktop application using HTTP for the communication backend.
>   Or perhaps it's an iOS app providing over-the-air access to documents.
>   Whatever your reason, CocoaHTTPServer can get the job done.