# How to make iPhone app sync data through laptop?

Tags: ios, ipad

Currently my application is getting data from remote server through web services. But some times user are in area where network is rarely available. So in that case I just want to sync data for application through their laptop (window or mac).

For example I need to sync 100 images in to the app. I create an environment on laptop where I create a folder and keep images there and once iPhone get connected to laptop through wifi all images get synced with the application.

However I don't want automatically it can be usually on button action. But please guide me is there any way?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230443/ios-filesharing-without-itunes/10398342#10398342

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a web service on the laptop and use that to do the storage.  I have done similar things and I have gone the route of storing data locally in a Core Data model and then syncing to a server when the user comes back within range.