# Exporting files over WIFI to a computer from an iPhone app -

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, wifi

I'm hoping that someone could point me in the right direction as I have no experience of network programming. I need to give the user the ability to export a file to their computer via WIFI (like an FTP server), much like certain apps such as AirSharing do by displaying a web address (e.g. 192.168.3.1:8080) that the user simply types into their computer web browser to access the files.

But I cannot find anything on the internet that points me in the direction of how to implement this. I've followed the code to publish a network service using Apple's NSNetSerice and CFNetService Programming Guide and although it builds and runs, it does not show up anywhere from my Mac and I don't know how to specify the web address. I have no knowledge of TCP or what it does.

Furthermore, none of the Apple provided sample projects (WiTap, BonjourWeb, Cryptoblahblah) seem to help do what I want (and they're really complicated as well)

Does anyone know if I'm going along the right track or if there is any advice I could follow? I would be happy to post some sample code if you like.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8417364/1311910

Comment: than q it's work for me

Comment: https://github.com/vodkhang/CocoaHTTPServer-Iphone

I got FUll solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes .
You can Do this TO using this Sample Code

[iPhoneHttpServer project](http://github.com/vodkhang/CocoaHTTPServer-Iphone)

Note:Feel free to use at your own risks, but feel free to send me an email if you have any query. vodkhang@gmail.com or visit my blog at : vodkhang.com

Answer (score 1):

you can try example transfer wifi

https://github.com/vodkhang/CocoaHTTPServer-Iphone