# Offline Viewing for Box view API assets?

Tags: box-view-api

I'd like to leverage the Box View API to display content in an app that works offline. Is there a good way to do this? I'm able to download the assets as a set of SVG and text files, but it seems that the viewer.js requires me to run a web server. Would I have to build my own viewer to handle the svg and text files in my app if I wanted offline viewing of the assets or is there a better/easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is likely to utilize a web server library/framework on the platform you're developing for, along with viewer.js. I'm assumning you're working on mobile, in which case it looks like there are some solutions for both [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417321/run-a-webserver-on-an-ios-device) and [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509851/web-server-for-android).