# Where can I find out about coding a website to my app?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just found out that an iPhone can act as a web server to access the app's data. I'm using Xcode. How do I extend my app's capabilities so that users can edit app data using a Mac. Where can I learn about this? Can you give me summary and a website please?

I hope it's using Apache Tomcat. I suppose I have to build a website to process and display the app's data. I wonder if iPhone supports jsp since it's using UNIX. I really don't want to use PHP.

Currently [Money Manager](http://realbyteapps.com/xe/9798) has that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for [embedded iOS web server](https://www.google.com/search?q=embedded%20iOS%20web%20server) returns a few solutions:

- [Run a webserver on an iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417321/run-a-webserver-on-an-ios-device)
- [A small, lightweight, embeddable HTTP server for Mac OS X or iOS applications](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)
- [Lightweight GCD based HTTP server for OS X & iOS](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)

You will be unlikely to fit `php` or `tomcat` onto an iOS device; the lack of memory and processing power will be technically challenging.

Apple will also likely take a negative view of the inclusion of a general purpose scripting language in any app your submit to the App Store.